# asp.net core 2.0 unable to delete PreCompiledViews.dll

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an asp.net core 2.0 web application.

When I publish it to a web server (using a UNC path), the [AppName].PrecompiledViews.dll becomes locked and I'm unable to delete it (and therefore can't re-publish the app).

I've tried manually deleting the file(s) - everything deletes fine, except for this one dll... and I don't have permission to go and restart the IIS worker process to free the lock, so I'm at a loss as to what to do... waiting for the app to recycle is my current best plan.

Any suggestions are welcome.

> (Using the following:)
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017  Version 15.4.2
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.4.2+27004.2006 Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.7.02046
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual Basic 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA538 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2017
>
> Visual C# 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA538 Microsoft Visual C# 2017
>
> Visual F# 4.1   00369-60000-00001-AA538 Microsoft Visual F# 4.1
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.9.00809.2
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.0.30925.0 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017
>
> ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   1.0 Provides languages services
>   for ASP.NET Core Razor.
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.50921.0 For additional
>   information, visit https://www.asp.net/
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.0.30915.0 Azure App Service Tools
>   v3.0.0
>
> Azure Data Lake Node   1.0 This package contains the Data Lake
>   integration nodes for Server Explorer.
>
> Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.9000.1 Microsoft Azure
>   Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.9000.1 Microsoft Azure
>   Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.10 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> Cookiecutter   3.0.17297.4 Provides tools for finding, instantiating
>   and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.
>
> Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0 Fabric Diagnostic Events
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> JavaScript UWP Project System   2.0 JavaScript UWP Project System
>
> Merq   1.1.17-rc (cba4571) Command Bus, Event Stream and Async Manager
>   for Visual Studio extensions.
>
> Microsoft Azure HDInsight Azure Node   2.2.9000.1 HDInsight Node under
>   Azure Node
>
> Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.2.9000.1 Language
>   service for Hive query
>
> Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   1.8 Microsoft
>   Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio
>
> Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.2.9000.1
>   Language service for Azure Stream Analytics
>
> Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Node   1.0 Azure Stream Analytics
>   Node under Azure Node
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2017 - v2.9.50719.1
>
> Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.3
>   Simplifying the configuration of continuous build integration and
>   continuous build delivery from within the Visual Studio IDE.
>
> Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
>   Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting
>   Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0 Microsoft Visual Studio VC
>   Package
>
> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   4.7.4-pre (c2d89eb) Support for
>   debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.
>
> Node.js Tools   1.4.10918.1 Adds support for developing and debugging
>   Node.js apps in Visual Studio
>
> NuGet Package Manager   4.4.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> Python   3.0.17297.4 Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates,
>   debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python
>   developers.
>
> Python - Django support   3.0.17297.4 Provides templates and
>   integration for the Django web framework.
>
> Python - IronPython support   3.0.17297.4 Provides templates and
>   integration for IronPython-based projects.
>
> Python - Profiling support   3.0.17297.4 Profiling support for Python
>   projects.
>
> R Tools for Visual Studio   1.2.30905.1244 Provides project system, R
>   Interactive window, plotting, and more for the R programming language.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61707.200 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0 Hosting json editor into a tool window
>
> TypeScript   2.3.5.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0 Interop layer for
>   hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.27004.2006 The
>   Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a
>   single universal app experience that can reach every device running
>   Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft
>   Windows 10 Software Development Kit.
>
> VisualStudio.IoT   1.0 Package with IoT components for Visual Studio
>
> VisualStudio.Mac   1.0 Mac Extension for Visual Studio
>
> WebJobs Tools v1.0.0   15.0.30915.0 WebJobs Tools v1.0.0
>
> Xamarin   4.7.10.33 (70936af) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   8.0.2.1 (HEAD/c2a33d8ea) Xamarin.Android
>   Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.2.1.0 (12e80e0) Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me deploying from appveyor to an azure server:

> You can configure the appOffline rule in the publishing profile (.pubxml). Add the `EnableMSDeployAppOffline` element to the PropertyGroup like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is the link to the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#errorfileinuse