# asp.net core 2.0 cannot load PrecompiledViews.dll when published

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I refered to;

link [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223635/asp-net-core-2-0-unable-to-delete-precompiledviews-dll)

link [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700399/deleting-precompiledviews-dll-from-asp-net-core-2-api?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But none of them helped.

The problem is that this works fine in my development machine. When I publish to an Azure app service, it gives below exception.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred: Could not load file or assembly 'FCL.Products.DriveSmart.Web.PrecompiledViews
.
.
.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FCL.Products.DriveSmart.Web.PrecompiledViews

I tried modifying the project file as per the 2nd link above but still the same. I made sure the file exists with the other assemblies.

Then I just created a sample project that is generated by VS2017 and just published it. That works and it also has a PreCompiledViews dll.

So, I can't figure out what is happening here.

Comment: Are you sure you added `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>` into the `<PropertyGroup>` in your `.csproj`? Because that resolved the issue for me.